# Google Places API and Google Javascript API - key

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm newbie for Google Places API, read it - https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/.
It requires a key. But I found other thing - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search
It works without key. What sense in this key, if it's required only for one method and not required for other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before I start: This answer is more a guess than based on facts.**

There is a limit for requests to the places-API, so the requests must be connected to either a website(HTTP-Host) or an API-project(created in the console) to be able to count them (and restrict the access when you've reached the limits).

The first link is related to the Places-webservice, this service is used for requests from server-side. When you send a request from serverside, it's not possible to determine from which website the request comes from(except you send a `HTTP-REFERER`-header, but this would be useless, because you can send the header with any value you like to). So you'll need the key here to identify your API-project and connect the request with your account.

The 2nd link is related to the Places-library of Maps-Javascript-API. Here it's possible to identify the website via javascripts `document.location` . When you take a look at the network-traffic when you load a map you'll see an request to

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent
```

This request has some additional parameters, one of these parameters is the location of the current website...the JS-API now is able to connect any request from the JS-API with your website.

---

But: although the Maps-Javascript-API works without a key, it's recommended to use there a key too. The benefit when you use a key(among others): When you use a key you have a google-account, and google is able to contact you before they start to restrict the access (e.g. to give you the chance to modify your application or purchase additional quota).